# Howto use .NET Code SDK v3 (RC1) with Visual Studio 2019 (16.2.5)

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I just installed VS2019 (16.2.5 Community) and then the .NET Core 3v RC-1 (x64) SDK.

After that, Core 3 doesn't show up as a target for a new ASP.NET Core project in VS2019. Searching the internet, I found some sources saying to enable a "Use preview SDK" (or so) option in Options>Project&Solutions>.NET Core. But that setting isn't available in my VS2019 version.

What can I do to enable VS2019 for .NET Core V3 projects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade VS 2019 to at least a 16.3 preview version.

As stated on [the download site](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0):

> .NET Core 3.0 should be used with the latest previews of Visual Studio.
>
> Visual Studio: Use the latest preview of Visual Studio 2019 installed
>   from the [Visual Studio preview channel](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/).
>
> Visual Studio for Mac: Use the latest preview of Visual Studio for Mac
>   8.2 installed from the [Preview channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/install-preview?view=vsmac-2019).

Answer (score 0):

update VS 2019 to preview or change your Project  xxxxx.csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```